# Jquery form field masking with default value that doesn't match the mask?

Tags: jquery, forms, mask

Does anyone know of a form field masking plugin or script that allows the field to have a default value that doesn't match the mask?

For example, a text field that says "Date of Birth" initially. When you click in it, "Date of Birth" disappears, and it says "mm/dd/yyyy", which fills in as you type, like "12/21/1970".

I've written a script that will show/clear the default value, and I've found plugins that will allow masking, but I'm not sure how to combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin ->

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

And you can do

```
$(function(){
    $("#product").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"Whatever value I want"});
});
```

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work. If I use this: $("#myField").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"Date of Birth"}); The field initially is empty. Then, when I click in it, it shows this text: "Date of BirthDate of Birth/Date of BirthDate of Birth/Date of BirthDate of BirthDate of BirthDate of Birth". What I want, is for it to initially show this text in the field: "Date of Birth". And then when I click in it, it should say: "mm/dd/yyyy". Which should be replaced by numbers as the user types.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a placeholder (if you're using bootstrap)

add placeholder="XXXX" as a clause in your input statement.